# Prism (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, prism

either I'm missing something or the ([patterns & practices Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF)) doesn't come with any templates or "guidance packages" to generate code. could someone confirm if I didn't install it properly or it is totally different from SCSF and doesn't have any codegen in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no template, or "guidance package" with Composite Application Guidance, aka Prism.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the reference implementation, reusable library code (named the Composite Application Library), documentation, QuickStart tutorials, and hands-on labs here:

[Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight - February 2009](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fa07e1ce-ca3f-4b9b-a21b-e3fa10d013dd&DisplayLang=en)

Answer (score 2):

You might find useful the [Prism Quick Start Kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/dphill/archive/2009/06/15/prism-quick-start-kit-update.aspx) created by David Hill. There you will find different visual studio templates (Shell and Module templates for WPF and Silverlight).

Please let me know if this helps,

Ezequiel Jadib

Answer (score 0):

When you install Prism, there will be a folder containing the samples and tutorials, so they can give you a better idea.